# Manipulate string from input field into separate arrays depending on whether characters are separated by commas or spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I have a form input field which I need to get the string value from and and group the inputs into separate arrays based on the weather the words end in a comma or space.

I tried taking the input string then spliting the string using comma as a separator, then pushing that to the commaArray, then filtering through that array to get values separated by spaces and pushing that to the spacesArray.
I haven't had much success. I also need to group the last word in the input field with the spaces array so basically if it does not end in comma the word is grouped with the spaceSeparatedArray.

I have added code and recreated in stackblitz too - link below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-ss6jy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

> **Input String**:
>   "a, b, cd ef gh, ijkl, mnop"
>
> **Desired Output Arrays:** 
>     commaSeparatedArray = ["a", "b", "gh", "ijkl"] 
> spaceSeparatedArray = ["cd", "ef", "mnop"]

HTML

```
<form
[formGroup]="aForm"
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

Value: {{ aForm.value | json }}

  <label>Comma Separator</label>
  
  <input
  formControlName="inputString"
  >
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    valuesArray: [];
    
    
  aForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ){
    this.aForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      inputString: new FormControl()
    })

  }
  // INPUT: 
  // a, b, cd ef gh, ijkl mnop

    onSubmit() {   
      let stringIn = this.aForm.get('inputString').value;
      let commaSeparatedArray = [];
      let spaceSeparatedArray = [];

      stringIn = stringIn.split(',');
      for(let i = 0; i <= stringIn.length; i++) {
        commaSeparatedArray.push(stringIn[i]);
      }
           

      spaceSeparatedArray = commaSeparatedArray.filter(a=> a.includes(' '));

      // OUTPUT 

      console.log("SpaceSeparatedArray:  " +spaceSeparatedArray)

      console.log("CommaSeparatedArray:  " + commaSeparatedArray);
  

    }
}
```

***Thank You***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const str = "a, b, cd ef gh, ijkl, mnop"

const commaSeparatedArray = str.split(' ')
.filter(s => s.slice(-1) === ',').map(s => s.replace(',', ''));

console.log(commaSeparatedArray);

const spaceSeparatedArray = str.split(' ')
.filter(s => s.slice(-1) !== ',');

console.log(spaceSeparatedArray);
```